# Ajax POST fire when close button clicked on modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that will do a ajax post when Submit has been clicked, but now I want to have a choice to close the modal but as soon as I click on 'Close' it still do the ajax post. I don't want to do a ajax post when 'Close' button has been clicked. I am not sure how to handle this situation.

Modal

```
<div id="ModelView" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button id="close" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Add Session</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" id="rateId" />
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Client</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="clientSelect">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lessons</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="SelectLessonCounter">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>From</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component">
                        <input id="from" size="16" type="text" readonly="true" />
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <i class="icon-time"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Till</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component">
                        <input id="till" size="16" type="text" readonly="true" />
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <i class="icon-time"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="subjectSelect">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="typeSelect">
                        <option value="<%# (int)Genius.Models.Enums.RateType.Tutoring %>">Tutoring </option>
                        <option value="<%# (int)Genius.Models.Enums.RateType.Couching %>">Couching </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input id="dontCount" type="checkbox" />
                    Don't Count
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a id="btnDoneEdit" href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">Done</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax Post

```
$("#ModelView").modal("show").on("hidden", function (a, b, c) {

                    if (a.target.localName != 'div')
                        return;

                    var d = {
                        id: 0,
                        SubjectId: $("#subjectSelect").val(),
                        ClientId: $("#clientSelect").val(),
                        From: f + " " + $("#from").val(),
                        Till: f + " " + $("#till").val(),
                        DontCount: $("#dontCount").is(":checked"),
                        Type: $("#typeSelect").val(),
                        LessonCounter: $("#SelectLessonCounter").val()
                    }


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Api/UpdateTimeTable.ashx",
                        data: JSON.stringify(d),
                        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                            var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
                            if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
                                window.location = window.location;
                            }
                            if (ct.indexOf('text') > -1) {
                                alert(response);
                                window.location = window.location;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("There seems to be a problem. " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

                });
```

Comment: A link to the particular modal plugin would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my modal, I changed my jquery a bit and it works fine now.

```
$("#ModelView").modal("show").on(
    //$(document).on("click", '#btnDoneEdit', function (e) {
    $('#btnDoneEdit').click(function (e) {
                        // e.preventDefault();
                        alert("Hi");
                        //if (a.target.localName != 'div')
                        //    return;

                        var d = {
                            id: 0,
                            SubjectId: $("#subjectSelect").val(),
                            ClientId: $("#clientSelect").val(),
                            From: f + " " + $("#from").val(),
                            Till: f + " " + $("#till").val(),
                            DontCount: $("#dontCount").is(":checked"),
                            Type: $("#typeSelect").val(),
                            LessonCounter: $("#SelectLessonCounter").val()
                        }

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Api/UpdateTimeTable.ashx",
                            data: JSON.stringify(d),
                            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                                var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
                                if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
                                    window.location = window.location;
                                }
                                if (ct.indexOf('text') > -1) {
                                    alert(response);
                                    window.location = window.location;
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("There seems to be a problem. " + errorThrown);
                            }
                        });

                    })
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind the ajax call to the on('hidden') event, but to the click event on the submit button.

[UPDATE]
(I don't know the modal plugin, but it should be something like this:)

```
$("#ModelView").modal("show");

             /*EDIT*/ 
            $(document).on( "click", '#btnDoneEdit', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
            /*EDIT end */


                var d = {
                    id: 0,
                    SubjectId: $("#subjectSelect").val(),
                    ClientId: $("#clientSelect").val(),
                    From: f + " " + $("#from").val(),
                    Till: f + " " + $("#till").val(),
                    DontCount: $("#dontCount").is(":checked"),
                    Type: $("#typeSelect").val(),
                    LessonCounter: $("#SelectLessonCounter").val()
                }


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Api/UpdateTimeTable.ashx",
                    data: JSON.stringify(d),
                    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                        var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
                        if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
                            window.location = window.location;
                        }
                        if (ct.indexOf('text') > -1) {
                            alert(response);
                            window.location = window.location;
                        }
                    $("#ModelView").modal("hide");

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("There seems to be a problem. " + errorThrown);
                    }
                }); 


            });
```

Comment: Can you perhaps give me an example? I am still a newbie at this

Comment: Just went through the code again,it is suppose to be bind on('hidden'). That event will show the modal but now if I click to close the modal it should not do the ajax post and when I click on 'Done' it should do the ajax post.

Comment: Thank you so much it works, but now when I click on 'Done' my modal hide and only if I submit the second time the ajax get called. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: See my edit, I moved the "hide" part into the success function of the ajax call. Check, if that does the trick.

Comment: I have moved it like you suggested but the problem still stay the same. The ajax only fire at the second attempt. If I click on 'Done' it hides then I have to get it to appear again then only the ajax event get called.

Comment: Any errors on the console? Have you tried to add console.log(d); after the declaration of 'var d=...' just to check if the values are correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31662/discussion-between-g-man-and-bouscher)

Comment: Try moving the click event bind on #btnDoneEdit outside of the modal hidden event bind just for a test. If that works then it is something to do with the life cycle on the way you are performing the nested event bind.

Comment: I see the issue you were having before in Bouscher's edit, you were binding the "shown" event just after the "shown" event was fired so it was not until "shown" was fired the second time that your click event bind on the done button was property set and fired.

Comment: @Justin3o9 join the chat and help us resolve this. And have a look at the twitter bootstrap docu, show is the method to open the modal, shown is the event fired immediately after the thing appears. So I thought show().on("shown") should be correct. Apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: @bouscher I fixed my jquery, see answer

Comment: @G-Man Good for you. I can't say I totally understand the construct with '.on(' and then no event specified, but what counts is that it works. You should accept your own answer then as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should make an own function for the ajax post and bind it to the onclick event from the button:

```
<input type="Button" value="Done" onclick="ajaxCall()" />
```

...

```
function ajaxCall()
{
$.ajax({...)};
}
```